# How would I make a reporting chat system using a trigger command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need to make it so players can report other players who curse or other bad stuff. So I would start with:
/scoreboard objectives add report trigger
Then people type to report:
/trigger report set 1
But then how would I put this in? Ideally, they would be kicked:
/kick @a[score_report_min=1] {text:"You have been reported and kicked"}

this did not work! Am I doing something wrong? What can I do?

Comment: What you have currently would kick the person who was doing the reporting (if `/kick` even worked in command blocks). If a player types `/trigger report set 1`, which player is it assumed they're reporting?

Comment: They are reporting the person who cursed or whatever. They just get their username, and type it in.

Comment: What @colorfusion is saying is that using `/trigger` can only effect the player actually entering it, not some other player.  They only person that would ever be kicked is the person doing the reporting, at least with this setup.

Comment: Hmm. Do you think I could give everyone a book, and when you click the chat it tp's you to a room, where you can type in the playername?

Comment: That sounds like a massive hole for abuse. Use book, type in random character name you don't like, system auto-boots character. Rinse, repeat ad nauseum.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to select a player from what someone typed into a book.

Comment: @colorfusion: Actually, there may be a way. Executing a `tellraw` against `@a` based on another `tellraw`.

Comment: @MBraedley Not quite sure what you mean here, how would a `tellraw` be based on another `tellraw`, or get a name out of a book?

Comment: Do you need to use the trigger command?

Comment: @colorfusion sorry, triggered by another `tellraw` (or book).  You can `/execute @a[tag=!target] ~ ~ ~ tellraw @p[tag=target] {text:"JSON message"}`.  There's more that's needed, obviously, but I think this would be a start.

Comment: @MBraedley Still confused at what you mean. How would the target tags be applied? Wouldn't that send the person with the "target" tag one message for every person online? (Or, if there's multiple people with the target tag, one of them may get no messages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do what you want just in a different way. (This I did in 1.8)  You could give everyone a book with a command.  This could /tp them to a room.[image]
  Under the floor of the room hide these commands connected to a clock of your choice(I used a hopper clock).
`/testfor @p[r=10]`  This will test for a player within a radius of 10.  If a player is within the radius a comparator will activate this command. `/give @p minecraft:writable_book`[image]
Have them write what they want to report in their book and place it in a trapped chest, connected to a hopper that places the item in a larger chest.  Then have them push a button to report.[image] .The report button should have 2 command blocks hidden behind it, one that clones the chest under the hopper to another room, and another that tells the player the report was sent `/say @p Report Filed`.  This is optional, but if you wanted to you could have a *tellraw* command that tells the owner of the world when someone is reported. `/tellraw (name) Someone has been reported`  it would look something like this:[image]
.You could then go to the room where the chest was cloned and read the reports, but you would have to kick or suspend the players yourself.

> This is a site with a book command generator:

https://www.minecraftjson.com/